# Getting Error 22 for dynamically naming a downloaded files using request from Python

Tags: python, request, file-management

So I'm trying to automate a daily download in jupyter and trying to name it adding the date and time of the download but I get this error 22:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Emilio\\Downloads\\BonosMX_2021-09-29_01:26:40_PM.xlsx'
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
import requests
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

url='www.xyz.com/file.xyz'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
print(r.headers.get('content-type'))
fechaDes = datetime.now().strftime("_%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S_%p")
path = r"C:\Users\Emilio\Downloads\BonosMX" + fechaDes + ".xlsx"
open(path, 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is quite fussy about what you can put into paths.  Try this:

```py
fechaDes = datetime.now().strftime("_%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S_%p")
```

In general stick to `_` and `-` as separators... and be aware that windows *also* has limits on path length which are quite easy to hit.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Feel free to accept if it solves the problem :)  Note that even when you can get away with : in paths (e.g. Linux) not all applications will handle them: e.g. evince will [used to] baulk, thinking you are passing it a url `file://`.

Comment: Yes. I tried to but I can't find that option...

Comment: Hah---it's next to the vote count; but no matter, the main thing is it's solved :)

Comment: Haha I see! It's the tick! You deserve two ticks for also teaching me to vote lol

Answer (score 0):

The "OS" in "OSError" hinted me so the time format was using ":" which cannont be used in file names on Windows so I just replaced them with "-" and now it works!